# Don't remove class when hovering target div

Tags: jquery, jquery-hover

So far I am stuck here. I want to toggle class on hover but don't want to remove class if cursor is on target div. My code

```
$(".filter-btn").hover(function () {
    var target = $(this).next();
    target.toggleClass("visible");
});
```

It works partially. As when I remove cursor from `filter-btn` it removes `visible` class from target div. What I need is I don't want to remove `visible` class when cursor is hovered on target div

Comment: You want to hide div on btn hover and show it when hovering off btn?

Comment: I mean visible class will be added only onhover.

Comment: then use `mouseleave`  `$(".filter-btn").mouseleave(function () {
    var target = $(this).next();
    target.toggleClass("visible");
});`

Comment: You're contradicting yourself, you want to toggleClass on hover or add it?